# Mysql using the whole CPU, can't explain why

Tags: mysql

Any idea of what is happening? It's swapping, but why the 30 mysql instances?

[image]

Comment: What OS / version? I suspect those are threads of a single MYSQL process.

Comment: Also see if you have some long running queries. e.g. mysqladmin processlist

Comment: thank you for the long queries suggestion, i will check that once that the load returns to abnormal. I don't really think mysql to be the bottleneck, but i will try to debug that.

Answer (score 0):

As htop indicates, you system seems to hang into huge iowait.
The 30 mysql instances are probably because you got 30 connections to your mysql server.

Comment: It's a ssd only server, I don't understand how that is possible.

Comment: Can you maybe post output of iotop and/or vmstat, iostat?